Why does cloning this repo using eGit create two entries in the Eclipse Project Explorer?
Using eGit in Eclipse. when I clone this repo:
https://github.com/nicomp42/FunWithCereal-001
I am not using Smart Import
I get two entries in the Eclipse Project Explorer:

My Eclipse is Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
Build id: 20230608-1333

Because it contains two projects (a project is a folder with a .project file): FunWithCereal-master and FunWithCereal.

What kind of import did you use? Can you more completely explain the steps that got you here?

I used eGit: File/Import/Projects from Git/Clone URI, then I took all the defaults.

The default of the Projects from Git import wizard is Import existing Eclipse projects. In the Project Explorer view menu (the three dots) you can choose the Projects Presentation: Flat (this is the default and what you have) or Hierarchical (in your case, FunWithCereal would be shown nested in FunWithCereal-master. If you just want to get rid of FunWithCereal-master in the Project Explorer view, delete it without its content.

Your repo has a .project file inside of https://github.com/nicomp42/FunWithCereal-001/tree/master/FunWithCereal-master and another one inside of: https://github.com/nicomp42/FunWithCereal-001/tree/master/FunWithCereal-master/FunWithCereal
Each .project maps to a new project inside of Eclipse. You should probably remove the internal one and configure the PYTHONPATH properly only on the external.
See: https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for more details on how to configure the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: source folders inside of pydev).
